# Is it possible to convert CSS code to dart code

Tags: css, flutter, dart

There is a website called framer[www.framer.com] which lets you to create layouts and UIs and the site will generate the CSS code for the layout which you created[sample image in the link] and now how do I convert that code to dart. I don't know much about CSS. It will be super handy to convert CSS code to Dart and use it in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [link](https://drawcall.github.io/c2f/) CSS to Flutter

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31547580)

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly the same thing as your question, you may find a solution in this article which is going from design in AdobeXD to dart code for Flutter. Offers the same type of workflow from prototype design to code.

[Flutter AdobeXD Plugin](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-adobe-xd-support-for-flutter-4b3dd55ff40e)

Comment: That was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is sadly no way of converting CSS to Dart. They work very differently so you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Or what about JSX to Dart? and of course they are different as well.

Comment: @GaneshSivakumar Since CSS goes with HTML the structure is very very different, so I would be shocked if there was a converter that actually does anything useful. I dont have much experience with JSX but again, I would be shocked if there was anything that is better than just doing it by hand.

Comment: @GaneshSivakumar As a sidenote. Tools like Framer.com are usually only used for prototyping. Most people still write their own, optimized UI before you actually go into production/release. This is because the Code generated by these Tools is very inefficient and messy. So running it through a converter(if it existed) would mess it up even more. My advice would be to just make a prototype with framer, make sure it looks and feels good, and then recreate it in Flutter.

Comment: Ok I'll go with creating a prototype with framer and recreating it in flutter!

Comment: @GaneshSivakumar Good luck!

Comment: There is s tool check this out https://drawcall.github.io/c2f/